# Gravity Forms Error

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I keep trying to setup a notification when a form is submitted but I'm not getting the emails. When I go back in to edit the notification, it is not there. It's like it is not saving that. Then I noticed this on the notifications page: `function WP_List_Table::get_columns() must be over-ridden in a sub-class.` Any idea what that means?

Note: It is saving the submissions in the entries area of the plugin.

Answer (score 48):

There is a simple fix for this without upgrading Gravity Forms, but you'd have to edit a plugin file for Gravity Forms.

in notification.php, in the class

GFNotificationTable extends WP_List_Table {
...

Add this method:

```
    function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
                'name' => 'Name',
                'subject' => 'Subject'
                );
        return $columns;
    }
```

The same solution can be applied to any plugin where you're seeing this problem. The columns array just needs to match the names set as $this->_column_headers.

Comment: Please note that the answer below is also relevant to fixing the issue. You should also add the above function to the file: `form_settings.php` inside `class GFConfirmationTable extends WP_List_table { ...`

Answer (score 41):

Adding to the previous answer, to fully fix the problem you'll need to also place that same function:

```
function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
                'name' => 'Name',
                'subject' => 'Subject'
                );
        return $columns;
    }
```

In the GF `form_settings.php` file under the class `GFConfirmationTable` extends `WP_List_Table`.

The first fixes the `Notifications` error and this fixes the `Confirmations` error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I didn't want to upgrade my Gravity forms license for such a simple fix/problem that I strongly feel Gravity should of offered as a free upgrade patch release or at the least, they should of offered an instructional post like this Q&A did!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. Once I put the license key into the settings, I was able to download the update. Installed and the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to add it to:
class GFAddOnFeedsTable extends WP_List_Table of file "class-gf-feed-addon.php" in includes/addons folder in order for add ons to work.

```
function get_columns() {
    $columns = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'subject' => 'Subject'
            );
    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this code inside `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php`

Copy and paste this code inside the function `public function get_columns()` at line 872.

```
$columns = array(
'name' => 'Name',
'subject' => 'Subject'
);
return $columns;
```

Answer (score -2):

I have tried this code snippet and it worked!

```
function get_columns() {
    $columns = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'subject' => 'Subject'
            );
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: This needs some further explanation to be useful. How would the OP apply this to their given problem?